# Can I combine Standard errors of coefficients with an unbalanced data set?

Tags: standard-error, regression-coefficients

I have just read the answers to the question ...... [Adding coefficients to obtain interaction effects - what to do with SEs?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3653/adding-coefficients-to-obtain-interaction-effects-what-to-do-with-ses/21626#21626)
.......and found this really helpful! I am looking to do something similar in R, but I have slightly different sample sizes between groups. Can I still use the same equation to combine the two errors to give me the new Std. error?

Thank you in advance for any help

Crystal