# How to correctly calculate linear model variable effects?

Tags: regression, modeling, standard-error

I'd like to estimate the unique effects for each variable in a linear model, 
however I am unsure if I calculating these correctly.

I am using a model estimated using each of the variables in my data plus a 
binary interaction with each variable, e.g. `y ~ x + x:z` where x is a vector and 
z is two factors which is present in x. Doing this in R I believe a two levels factor is simply c(0,1).

From what understand I can calculate the individual effects of the variables 
for each case of the binary interaction term is as follows:

- When the interaction term is 0, the variable effect of x on y is the 
  estimated model coefficient for x
- When the interaction term is 1, the variable effect of x on y is the 
  estimated model coefficient for x plus the coefficient for the interaction 
  term of x:z

Assuming this is correct I would also like to calculate the standard errors 
associated with the each effect. I looked at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3653/adding-coefficients-to-obtain-interaction-effects-what-to-do-with-ses) which states 
that the associated standard errors can be calculated as follows `sqrt(x + x:z + 
2*cov(x,x:z))`. This however produces much smaller standard errors compared to 
the non-interaction term effects. This makes me assume I am doing something 
wrong. Could you tell me the correct way to estimate these effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, doesn't R give you the standard errors?

Second, it is very rarely sensible to include an interaction term without the main effects that are part of that interaction. Except in very unusual circumstances, I think you should be including z in the model.

Why?

Well here are predicted values for y from $y = b_0 + b_1*x + b_2*z$

x     z     y

0     0     $b_0$

0     1     $b_0$

100   0     $b_0 + 100b_1$

100   1     $b_0 + 100b_1 + 100b_2$

So, you are forcing there to be no effect of z when x is 0. Is this what you want?

Comment: Sorry I should have wrote that z is also in x. What I specifically want is the effect sizes for each of the variables in x given z.

Comment: R does give the standard errors but not for the unique effects as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please name all your predictor variables.  I can't make sense of "z is two factors which is present in x."