# How to construct the standard error for the sum of three parameter estimates corresponding to two dummy variables and their interaction term?

Tags: regression, interaction, standard-error

I have a simple multiple linear regression model with an interaction term, and I would like to construct a standard error to support interpretation. My goal is to construct a standard error for an estimate of the sum of coefficients β1, β2, and β3. Suppose the dependent variable Y is income. Suppose X1 refers to gender such that X1=0 represents an individual who is "not female" and X1=1 represents one who is female. Suppose X2 refers to education, where X2=0 means the individual has no college degree and X2=1 means they have a college degree. A third term is included where X1 and X2 are multiplied, and the parameter for this interaction term is β3.

```latex
Y = β0 + β1*X1 + β2*X2 + β3X1*X2 + ε
```

I want to compare the income of a college-educated female with the income of a non-female with no college degree. My understanding is this would require β1, β2, and β3 to be summed. How would I construct the standard error for the sum of these three coefficients? Below is the covariance matrix. I have consulted [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189408/standard-error-for-the-sum-of-regression-coefficients-when-the-covariance-is-neg/625465?noredirect=1#comment1165922_625465), and a few textbooks including Wooldridge, but have not been successful. Can anyone provide some clarity here along with a citation from a published source? It would also be helpful to know if I am approaching this incorrectly. Thanks.

|  | X1 | X2 | X1*X2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 2.105816e-03 | -1.477463e-05 | -2.021945e-03 |
| X2 | -1.477463e-05 | 1.889486e-04 | -2.801293e-05 |
| X1*X2 | -2.021945e-03 | -2.801293e-05 | 2.290629e-03 |

Comment: Apply the bilinearity property as explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721.  That is also explained in the thread you reference, so could you please explain how it was "not ... successful"?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The approach I take at the moment uses Var(X1) + Var(X2) + Var(X1*X3) + 2*Cov(X1, X2) + 2*Cov(X1,X1*X2) + 2*Cov(X2, X1*X2), which ultimately produces a SE of ~0.02135248. Is this the correct application of the bilinearity property? In textbooks I have looked for specific examples, but not found a citation I prefer. E.g., Example 7.9 in Wooldridge's Introductory Econometrics textbook has a specific example with this model setup and comparison of interest, but the book only explains coefficient interpretation, not SEs.

Comment: The form of your formula looks correct but the notation is confusing: the variances and covariances concern the *parameter estimates* $\hat\beta_i$ rather than the variables themselves.

Comment: Thank you very much!