# interpretation of interaction-term in linear regression, with and without main-effect

Tags: regression, interaction, interpretation

In a case-control study including men and women of various ages, I wish to investigate if there is a difference in a measured variable (`X`) between cases and controls. The data are stored in a dataframe/tibble `d` as such:

```
# A tibble: 1,103 × 4
     CaCo Gender   Age        X
   <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>    <dbl>
1    Case  Woman    59 1.225700
2    Case  Woman    61 1.153512
3    Case  Woman    50 1.125951
4    Case  Woman    30 1.316410
5    Case    Man    28 1.248292
6    Case    Man    52 1.226141
7    Case  Woman    45 1.332503
8    Case    Man    31 1.272777
9    Case    Man    30 1.150000
10   Case  Woman    41 1.186069
# ... with 1,093 more rows

xtabs(~ CaCo + Gender, data = d)
         Gender
CaCo      Man Woman
  Control 401   271
  Case    256   175
```

The reference category for the `CaCo`-term is `Control` and for the `Gender`-term it is `Man`.

I use linear regression `lm` in R to apply model `m1`:

```
#-----
Call:
lm(formula = "X ~ CaCo + Age + Gender + CaCo:Gender", data = d)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.5736 -0.1111 -0.0128  0.1007  1.1256 

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           1.0924392  0.0276614  39.493  < 2e-16 ***
CaCoCase              0.0117859  0.0141087   0.835    0.404    
Age                  -0.0029474  0.0004465  -6.601 6.36e-11 ***
GenderWoman           0.0037238  0.0138262   0.269    0.788    
CaCoCase:GenderWoman  0.0325746  0.0220949   1.474    0.141    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1757 on 1098 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.05002,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.04655 
F-statistic: 14.45 on 4 and 1098 DF,  p-value: 1.662e-11
#----
```

It is my understanding that the coefficients should be interpreted as follows:

- The `CaCoCase`-term represents the differences between cases and
  controls, among males (male cases have 0.0117859 higher levels than
  male controls - not significant).
- The `GenderWoman`-term represents the difference between genders,
  among controls (female controls have 0.0037238 higher levels than
  male - not significant)
- The `CaCoCase:GenderWoman`-term represents how much greater the
  difference between cases and controls is among females than among
  males (i.e. female cases have 0.0117859 + 0.0325746 higher levels
  than male controls).

I hope I am right so far...?

Now, because I don't believe there is an effect of gender on `X`, but I suspect that the difference between cases and controls is mainly observed among women, I drop the main `Gender`-term and keep only the interaction `CaCo:Gender`, to get model `m2`:

```
#-----
Call:
lm(formula = "X ~ CaCo + Age + CaCo:Gender", data = d)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.5736 -0.1111 -0.0128  0.1007  1.1256 

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              1.0924392  0.0276614  39.493  < 2e-16 ***
CaCoCase                 0.0117859  0.0141087   0.835   0.4037    
Age                     -0.0029474  0.0004465  -6.601 6.36e-11 ***
CaCoControl:GenderWoman  0.0037238  0.0138262   0.269   0.7877    
CaCoCase:GenderWoman     0.0362984  0.0172355   2.106   0.0354 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1757 on 1098 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.05002,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.04655 
F-statistic: 14.45 on 4 and 1098 DF,  p-value: 1.662e-11
#-----
```

The model statistics are identical (as far as I can tell) between `m1` and `m2`. It appears that the `GenderWoman`-term from `m1` (the main effect of gender) have become `CaCoControl:GenderWoman` in `m2`, but I am assuming the interpretation is the same.

The only other difference between the models is the interaction term `CaCoCase:GenderWoman`, where the coefficient is slightly larger with a smaller error and consequently a much lower p-value.

The effect of the interaction term appears identical between `m1` and `m2` when illustrated using the `effects`-package:

```
library(effects)
plot(effect("CaCo:Gender", m1))
```

[image]

(As a side note, when modelling men and women separately by `X ~ CaCo + Age`, it appears clear that there is a difference between cases and controls among women, but not among men)

My questions are:

Are the interpretations of the coefficients the same between the models `m1`and `m2`? If so, what are the reasons they differ? If not, how should the coefficients be interpreted?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had forgot about this… If anyone out there is interested, here is a long explanation:

Important to remember that the interpretation of the main effects depend on which categories were set as reference during modelling (in this case men and controls).

**The models are indeed identical!** In `m1`, the interaction-term (`CaCoCase:GenderWoman`) represents both the difference in CaCo-effect among men and women, as well as the difference in gender-effect among controls and cases.

In `m1`, to calculate the gender-effect (difference between men and women) among cases, one must sum up the gender-effect among controls (`GenderWoman`) and the difference in gender-effect among controls and cases (i.e. the interaction term `CaCoCase:GenderWoman`). Thus, among cases, women have 0.0037238 + 0.0325746 = 0.0362984 higher levels than men.

Similarly, in `m1`, to calculate the CaCo-effect (difference between controls and cases) among women, one must sum up the CaCo-effect among men (`CaCoCase`) and the difference in CaCo-effect among men and women (i.e. the interaction term `CaCoCase:GenderWoman`). Thus, among women, cases have 0.0117859 + 0.0325746 = 0.0443605 higher levels than controls.

In both cases, it is also possible to calculate the standard error of these sums: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3657.

*Importantly, in `m2`, above, I attempted to “drop” the `Gender`-term. **The fact is that because it is included in the interaction, it will also be included as a main effect by the model** (although not explicitly printed). I.e. the formula for `m2` could just as well have been written as `formula = "X ~ CaCo + Age + Gender + CaCo:Gender"`.*

In `m2` the size of the interaction-term is not explicitly returned by the summary function. Instead, the gender-effect is printed separately for controls (`CaCoControl:GenderWoman = 0.0037238`, identical to the `GenderWoman`-term from `m1`) and for cases (`CaCoCase:GenderWoman = 0.0362984`, same as in `m1` after summation).

By rearranging the order of the model-terms specified in the `formula` argument of the `lm` function, one can refocus the returned summary of the model, as such (`m3`):

```
Call:
lm(formula = "X ~ Gender + Age + Gender:CaCo", data = d2)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.5736 -0.1111 -0.0128  0.1007  1.1256 

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           1.0924392  0.0276614  39.493  < 2e-16 ***
GenderWoman           0.0037238  0.0138262   0.269  0.78772    
Age                  -0.0029474  0.0004465  -6.601 6.36e-11 ***
GenderMan:CaCoCase    0.0117859  0.0141087   0.835  0.40370    
GenderWoman:CaCoCase  0.0443605  0.0171180   2.591  0.00968 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1757 on 1098 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.05002,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.04655 
F-statistic: 14.45 on 4 and 1098 DF,  p-value: 1.662e-11
```

In `m3` the size of the interaction-term is not explicitly printed (same as for `m2`). Instead, the CaCo-effect is printed separately for men (`GenderMan:CaCoCase = 0.0117859`, identical to the `CaCoCase` term from `m1`) and for women (`GenderWoman:CaCoCase = 0.0443605`, same as in `m1` after summation). **(((This was what I was originally interested in!)))**

**All three models are identical**, but the summary of the models are returned in slightly different ways. Notice that all the conclusions from `m2` and `m3` were readily available already in `m1` by summing main-effects and interaction-effects appropriately.